# DBeaver, ClickHouse driver: How to show number of rows processed

Tags: clickhouse, dbeaver

`DBeaver Version`: CE 22.0.4

`Platform`: Windows 10

`ClickHouse Driver`: Yandex ClickHouse driver (server version 21.3+)

I use `DBeaver` to make query requests to my local `ClickHouse` instance. In the tutorial page (https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/optimize/sparse-primary-indexes) I see that the result of the following query shows a paramater `Processed 8.87 million rows`, as well as other stats like network speed.

```
SELECT URL, count(URL) as Count
FROM hits_NoPrimaryKey
WHERE UserID = 749927693
GROUP BY URL
ORDER BY Count DESC
LIMIT 10
```

```
┌─URL────────────────────────────┬─Count─┐
│ http://auto.ru/chatay-barana.. │   170 │
│ http://auto.ru/chatay-id=371...│    52 │
│ http://public_search           │    45 │
│ http://kovrik-medvedevushku-...│    36 │
│ http://forumal                 │    33 │
│ http://korablitz.ru/L_1OFFER...│    14 │
│ http://auto.ru/chatay-id=371...│    14 │
│ http://auto.ru/chatay-john-D...│    13 │
│ http://auto.ru/chatay-john-D...│    10 │
│ http://wot/html?page/23600_m...│     9 │
└────────────────────────────────┴───────┘

10 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.022 sec.
Processed 8.87 million rows,
70.45 MB (398.53 million rows/s., 3.17 GB/s.)
```

However in my `DBeaver` client I can't see this additional stats.

[image]

Is it possible to turn on this feature to show a number of rows processed? It seems very useful for optimizing queries.